# Xamarin Forms Maps Google only?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does the Xamarin Essentials Map control only work with Google Maps?  Or can it be used with Azure Maps or a different mapping service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Essentials.Map is not a "control", it is using a pre-installed map app on the device.

i.e. On Android it is using the `geo:` Uri scheme and and thus may prompt the user to pick which map application to use as more than one may support the `geo:` scheme (but on *most* Android devices, Google Maps is pre-installed thus it will be used if the user has not installed additional map applications.